# Scala implementation of a generic Heap

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance, variance

I'm trying to implement a very basic implementation of a generic Heap, and while I love the type checker, this is one of these occasions where I feel it's fighting me every step of the way.

The simplest expression I could write was:

```
trait Heap[A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def merge(as: Heap[A]): Heap[A]
  def insert(a: A): Heap[A]
  def findMin: A
  def deleteMin(): Heap[A]
}
```

This is fine, but concrete implementations "loose" their type as soon as `merge`, `insert` or `deleteMin` are called. That is, if `set` is of type `CustomHeap`, calling `set.deleteMin` is of type `Heap`.

After some struggle, I came up with the following definition that solved this problem:

```
trait Heap[A, Repr <: Heap[A, Repr]] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def merge(as: Repr): Repr
  def insert(a: A): Repr
  def findMin: A
  def deleteMin(): Repr
}
```

This is starting to get complicated, but works as expected: it's a generic `Heap`, and type isn't lost when calling `merge`, for example.

This definition is a bit cumbersome when one tries not to tie one's code to a specific implementation of `Heap`, though: variables can't be of type `Heap[A]` but something much more complex which I quickly quit trying to write.

In order to work around this limitation, I tried to use the `XxxLike` pattern found everywhere in the collection API, but this where I get stuck.

That's what I have so far:

```
trait Heap[A] extends HeapLike[A, Heap[A]]

trait HeapLike[A, +Repr <: HeapLike[A, Repr] with Heap[A]] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def merge(bs: Repr): Repr
  def insert(a: A): Repr
  def findMin: A
  def deleteMin(): Repr
}
```

This is quite a bit more complex and introduces a new trait just for the purpose of typing, but I could live with that - if it worked.

With this implementation, `HeapLike` is covariant on `Repr`, but `Repr` is a parameter of `merge` - a covariant type in contravariant position. I was not able to fix this.

I also tried to make `HeapLike` non-variant on `Repr`, which works fine until I try to actually mix the trait in:

```
sealed trait LeftistHeap[A] extends Heap[A] with HeapLike[A, LeftistHeap[A]] {
  def rank: Int
}
```

This yields the following error message:

```
error: illegal inheritance;
self-type this.LeftistHeap[A] does not conform to this.HeapLike[A,this.LeftistHeap[A]]'s selftype this.HeapLike[A,this.LeftistHeap[A]]
sealed trait LeftistHeap[A] extends Heap[A] with HeapLike[A, LeftistHeap[A]] {
```

I'm sure there's a simple way to get this whole thing to work - it's quite a bit more basic than the collection API which manages to do all this *and* be covariant on the elements contained in a collection, but I feel like I've hit a brick wall. Any suggestion, explanation, pointers... ?

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to compile even your first two traits (in scala 2.11): `<console>:11: error: covariant type Repr occurs in contravariant position in type Repr of value bs
         def merge(bs: Repr): Repr
`

Comment: If your `Heap` is intended to be mutable, all of your mutation methods (e.g. `merge`, `insert`, and `deleteMin` could have a return type of `this.type`, and you would return `this` for each implementation. That should let you completely avoid complex type signatures and abstract `Repr` types.

Comment: @Ashalynd that's odd - I just tried compiling my first two examples with scala 2.11.2, and they worked fine. The third one does fail with a covariant type in contravariant position error, but that was mentioned in my post. Did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: @Dylan my `Heap` is intended to be immutable, but I'd never seen `this.type` before. I'll look this up, but is there a particular reason why it can't be used in the case of an immutable structure?

Comment: I tried to compile your third example (without the LeftistHeap trait).

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo stating a return type of `this.type` generally makes it so that you can only return `this` from the method. That wouldn't make sense with an immutable object, since a method like `merge` should return a new instance rather than `this`.

Comment: A possible hint, since I don't have the time to flesh this out as an answer: check out the `CanBuildFrom` trait. Many of the standard library collections classes use that to implement append-ish operations. In the docs, they are often hidden away under `[user case]` tags, but you can find a "Full Signature". For example, check out `List`'s `++` method signature.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo check out update in my answer on adding variance support similar to standard Scala collections.

Comment: have a look at the recent blog entry by Rob Norris, it discusses exactly this question - https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html

I'll attempt to provide an answer using type classes as he suggests when I have a bit more time tonight.

Comment: For an example scala heap implementation, mutable.PriorityQueue is implemented as a heap with an underlying ResizableArray. See https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.scala.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, variance in Scala is pretty awesome and allows you to solve the problem much simplier.

Lets take your original `Heap` trait:

```
trait Heap[A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def merge(as: Heap[A]): Heap[A]
  def insert(a: A): Heap[A]
  def findMin: A
  def deleteMin(): Heap[A]
}
```

...in order for derived collections to maintain their "kind" after applying transformations you can do the following (I am demonstrating concept here, so I am stubbing methods with `???`. This code will compile but you'll obviously have to implement them to make your heap work in runtime):

```
class MyHeap[A] extends Heap[A] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = ???
  override def insert(a: A): MyHeap[A] = ???
  override def deleteMin(): MyHeap[A] = ???
  override def merge(as: Heap[A]): MyHeap[A] = ???
  override def findMin: A = ???
}
```

... and then you can do something like this:

```
val myHeap1 = new MyHeap[Int]
val myHeap2 = new MyHeap[Int]

val stillMyHeap1: MyHeap[Int] = myHeap1 insert 1
val stillMyHeap2: MyHeap[Int] = myHeap1 merge myHeap2
```

Note that `insert`, `deleteMin` and `merge` [return types are covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_return_type) (`MyHeap`).

Also note that `merge` takes argument of the same type (`Heap`), but you could also implement it to [take contravariant argument type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type) if you pleased (i.e. hypotetical base of `Heap`).

**UPDATE**

BTW, to make `Heap[A]` (or `MyHeap[A]`) preserve variance of its argument type `A`, just like standard Scala collections (for example: for `AnyVal` being a base of `Int`, have `Heap[AnyVal]` to be a base of `Heap[Int]`) you'll have to change your `Heap` trait like this:

```
trait Heap[+A] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def merge[B >: A](xs: Heap[B]): Heap[B]
  def insert[B >: A](x: B): Heap[B]
  def findMin: A
  def deleteMin(): Heap[A]
}
```

... and `MyHeap` like this:

```
class MyHeap[+A] extends Heap[A] {
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = ???
  override def insert[B >: A](x: B): MyHeap[B] = ???
  override def deleteMin(): MyHeap[A] = ???
  override def merge[B >: A](xs: Heap[B]): MyHeap[B] = ???
  override def findMin: A = ???
}
```

... and then you can play with it as follows:

```
val myHeap1 = new MyHeap[Int]
val myHeap2 = new MyHeap[Int]

val stillMyHeap1: MyHeap[Int] = myHeap1 insert 1
val stillMyHeap2: MyHeap[Int] = myHeap1 merge myHeap2

val myHeap3: MyHeap[AnyVal] = myHeap1
val myHeap4: MyHeap[AnyVal] = myHeap1 insert 'a'

val heap1: Heap[Int] = myHeap1
val heap2: Heap[AnyVal] = myHeap1
```

Note how `MyHeap[Int]` conforms to all of these:

- `MyHeap[AnyVal]` (`myHeap3`)
- `Heap[Int]` (`heap1`)
- `Heap[AnyVal]` (`heap2`)

And also note how `insert`ing `Char` into `MyHeap[Int]` produces `MyHeap[AnyVal]` (`myHeap4`). Since the result of this operation cannot be neither `MyHeap[Int]` nor `MyHeap[Char]` it falls back to common ancestor of two, which is `MyHeap[AnyVal]`

Comment: This is only part of the solution though, isn't it? As soon as an instance of `MyHeap` is handled as a generic `Heap`, this property is lost. Say, for instance, that you have a function that takes a `Heap`, adds a value to it and return the newly created instance. Even though under the hood, you know that the returned value is of type `MyHeap`, the compiler doesn't and you're left with a bare `Heap`. If the type of the representation was encoded in `Heap` (such as in my broken `HeapLike` trait), however, there would not be any such issue.